# connect android device via MQTT with ssl

Tags: java, android, ssl, mqtt, paho

I have created an MQTT Broker and a client in java. It works perfectly using SSL too.
With a broker server and a client both written in java using paho libs, enabling SSL is easy. We need just to swich the protocol in the url from tcp to ssl IE: ssl://.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:8883 and setting some props in te src code:

```
java.util.Properties sslClientProps = new java.util.Properties();
sslClientProps.setProperty("com.ibm.ssl.protocol", "TLSv1.2");
options.setSSLProperties(sslClientProps);
```

on the SSLContext

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
```

Than a secure and encrypted connection is created (checked sniffing the packets with WireShark).

Using a specific CA trusted certificate works well too (messaging.pem file)

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream certFile = MqttHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("messaging.pem");
Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(certFile);
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
TrustManager trustManager = TrustManagerUtils.getDefaultTrustManager(keyStore);
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextUtils.createSSLContext("TLSv1.2", null, trustManager);
options.setSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

**I need to use an Android Client and a custom MQTT Java Server Broker** (without using SSL, MQTT publish and subscribe works well from Android too).

The trouble seems related with the creation of the *SSLSocketFactory* from Android.

I did this tests:

1) Setting SSL props (as I did in the src of the java client as reported above)

2) passing the CA trusted certificate on Android client (as I did in the src of the java client as reported above)

3) generate the key store from the trusted CA in BouncyCastle format (compatible with Android) as reported here http://rijware.com/accessing-a-secure-mqtt-broker-with-android/ and pass the key store on Android client:

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream keyStoreFile = getAssets().open("raw_key_file");
//keystore trusted
KeyStore keystoreTrust = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");//Bouncy Castle format for Android
keystoreTrust.load(keyStoreFile, "mykeystorepassword".toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(keystoreTrust);
SLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
options.setSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

4) using local trust store (CA) and client certificate:

```
// use local trust store (CA)
TrustManagerFactory tmf;
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream srvIn = getAssets().open("messaging.pem");
Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(srvIn);
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
tmf.init(keyStore);
// load client certificate
KeyStore clientKeyStore = null;
InputStream clIn = getAssets().open("raw_key_file");
clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
clientKeyStore.load(clIn, "mykeystorepassword".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
kmf.init(clientKeyStore, "mykeystorepassword".toCharArray());
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
options.setSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Unfortunally with all the tests I still getting this error: **MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer**

```
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:604)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:89)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:590)
```

Maybe I still confusing with the certificates process. How to create these from scratch and using on server and client side (creating the keystore in BouncyCastle format compatible with Android) ?
Or Maybe I did something wrong using the SSLSocketFactory classes in Android...

Thanks, any suggestion is really approciated.

Comment: I'd like an answer to this too.